# Reference request: example of pointwise free module which is not projective

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I am looking for a **reference** for examples showing the following phenomena:
Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian ring, and let $F$ be an $A$-module such that for all $p \in Spec(A)$ it holds that $F_p$ is a free $A_p$-module, but $F$ it not a projective $A$-module.

Of course, such an $F$ must be infinitely generated and flat.

Comment: Are you sure you need not finitely generated? What if you take a non free but torsion free module over a Dedekind domain? I mean, take $K$ a number field of class number grater than $1$ and take a non principal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: @Ricky: In a Dedekind ring any ideal is projective. As pointed out in the question, $F$ is flat, hence projective if finitely generated.

Comment: Sorry, I read "... that is not free"!

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer in Exercise 19.12 of Eisenbud's book "Commutative algebra with a view...". It says the following:
we are working over the ring of integers Z,
and take the Z-module M of all rational numbers with square-free denominators. Then every localization of M as a prime is free,
but M is not projective.

Comment: Could you expand on the answer you found? It may be of interest to those who do not have access to the book.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese done.